# Hibernate and Spring Data, reattach entity

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am validating and uploading data in my webapp. In this process, I need to get user input, so the validating and uploading is split between 2 requests. In the 1st request I setup/fetch all the information and then save it in the session. This includes a Entity object that I later access in the 2nd request.

My question is how do I reattach the entity in the 2nd request so I don't get a LazyInitializationException? I have tried the following:

```
 // we need to reattach the entities to the jpa session to avoid lazy-initialization exceptions
    EntityManager manager = jpaContext.getEntityManagerByManagedType(myEntity.class);
    manager.merge(myEntity);
```

I am getting the error: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: No EntityManager with actual transaction available for current thread - cannot reliably process 'merge' call, even though I have the annotated the method with Spring's @Transactional.

These request method are Jersey REST service calls if that makes a difference. The jpa code lives in a commons jar file and this service is in the project that uses the commons jar.

Comment: whats with the non-JPA code? em.merge will re-attach

Comment: I didn't realize merge would re-attach. I'll change that. I still get a Transaction error though.